# How do I Simulate a clicking of a button in Unity with C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard

How would I be able to simulate the clicking of the escape button in Unity?

I have tried using the InputSimulator API, but that doesn't work. I have also tried unity Event.KeyboardEvent which didn't work either.

I am currently trying to conduce some UI tests in my game, to check that when the P button is clicked on the keyboard, the game pause menu object becomes active in the hierarchy.

I tried this, using the InputSimulator:

```
InputSimulator IS = new InputSimulatro();
IS.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_P);
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: It'll probably be helpfull if you'd give an example why you need that and an [mcve] wouldn't be too bad either.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Why do you need the button specifically? I'm assuing you have something bound to handle key presses. Why not just call the method instead of simulating pressing the button that calls the method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question but does [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) not work?
Something like SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");

Answer (score 0):

I found something in [Microsft Documentation](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator).. Did you tried this:

```
InputSimulator IS = new InputSimulator();
IS.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.P);
```

Comment: Hi, the InputSimulator doesn't work for me. There is no such function in it called `SimulateKeyDown`.

Comment: As shown in the link of Documentation, its inside a package which you can install.. Srry.. I thought it was native to System package of C#.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your response, I installed it before I tried it the first time, the function `SimulateKeyDown` doesn't exist for me. I've noticed that I am not the only one having this problem.